# Where to find deep learning based prediction model

Tags: deep-learning, prediction

I need to find a deep learning based prediction model, where can I find it?

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stack overflow , Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). And please post [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pytorch and Tensorflow pretrained models.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html

They can be automatically downloaded. There are some sample codes, that you can try:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in deep learning, I suggest you review the basics of it in cs231n stanford. Your question is a bit odd, because you first need to define your task specifically. Prediction is not a good description. You could look for models for classification, segmentation, object detection, sequence2sequence(like translation), and so on...
Then you need to know how to search through projects on github, and then you need to know python (in most cases), and then use a pretrained model or use your own dataset to train or fine-tune the model for that task. Then you could pray that you have found a good model for your task, after that you need to validate the results on a test set. However, implementation of a model for real-life scenarios is another thing that you need to consider many other things, and you usually need some online-learning strategy, like Federated Learning. I hope that I could help you.